# How to solve KeyError in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a warn command in discord.py аnd the program responds to me:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ivanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, *kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ivanb\OneDrive\Работен плот\ivan4o bot\main.py", line 87, in on_member_join
    warns[str(member.guild.name)][str(member.id)] = 0
KeyError: 'Youtube tutorial bot test'
```

I tried with this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)
        warns[str(member.guild.name)][str(member.id)] = 0
    
    with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(warns, f, indent=4)
```

And i'm getting the error from above.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `warns.setdefault(str(member.guild.name), {})[str(member.id)] = 0`.

Essentially, your statement has to dictionary element accesses. The second is a `__setitem__` -- it assigns a value to a key. But the first one is a `__getitem__` that is supposed to get the value (happening to be another dict) by the key of `str(member.guild.name)`. The second one works fine when there's no such element in the dict -- it simply creates one. But the first has to return something, and raises an error if the requested key is not present in the dictionary. `setdefault` looks if the key exists in the dict, and creates a new one with the specified ('default') value if it doesn't, and then returns the value.

Comment: @Ivan Parvanov, I forgot about setdefault. This is a much more elegant example than mine. Go with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends on what you expect the structure of your warns.json file to be. It looks like, based on your code, you expect the JSON data to be a dictionary with guild names as keys. Each of those guild names is associated with another dictionary that uses user IDs as keys. E.g.:

```
{
    "Guild 1": {
        "user1234": 0,
        "user5678": 2
    },
    "Guild 2": {
        "user91011": 0
    }
}
```

The problem appears to be that you are receiving a response for a guild name that doesn't exist in the data yet. Let's say, using the example above, we get a response for member who is in Guild 3. Well, Guild 3 doesn't exist yet, nor does any of its members, so `warns['Guild 3']['userID']` will throw a KeyError.

What you need to do is check if the guild already exists in the dictionary before trying to assign anything to a user ID.

```
guild_name = str(member.guild.name)
if guild_name not in warns:
    warns[guild_name] = {}
warns[guild_name][str(member.id)] = 0
```